# Matlab: Directly getting table into uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Consider the following [table](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) in Matlab

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
T = table(Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure,'RowNames',LastName)
```

If I try to create *`uitable`* as follows, I receive error

```
uit = uitable('Data', T)
```

Although the following works: (Except: *BloodPressure Variable should occupy two columns*)

```
TVN = T.Properties.VariableNames;
TRN = T.Properties.RowNames;
TData = T{:,:};
uit = uitable('Data', TData, 'ColumnName', TVN, 'RowName', TRN);
```

I want to know, Is there a shorter or direct way of doing this?

I am using R2014a.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like there is no more direct way than the one you use, and there's also no quick solution for multi-column headers (like 'BloodPressure'). I hope someone will come with a new idea.

Comment: @EBH thanks for replying